# Get register with ptrace PTRACE_GETREGS vs PTRACE_PEEKUSER performance

Tags: c, linux, performance, arm, ptrace

If I need to get the values of some registers with `ptrace` for example I need  r0 , r1  ,pc registers what way will give me better performance :

`int pc= ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKUSER,pid,60,0);`

`r0 = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKUSER,  pid, 0, NULL);`

`r1 = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKUSER,  pid, 4, NULL);`

Or get all registers with `PTRACE_GETREGS` and then use only the values I need?

How is that implement? Is `PTRACE_GETREGS` implement as a loop on `PTRACE_PEEKUSER` so if I don't need all the registers the best way is to use `PTRACE_PEEKUSER` as number of registers I need?

Is the performance depend on architecture (x86/Arm)?

Comment: You probably have to test it.  But I would guess that the overhead of making an extra system call is far greater than the cost of copying some extra data around.  So that would suggest you should use `PTRACE_GETREGS` as soon as you need more than one register.

Answer (score 1):

> How is that implement?

ptrace us arch dependent.

for **arm** in linux kernel ptrace implementation is
(arch/arm/kernel/ptrace.c)[https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/arm/kernel/ptrace.c#L784]

> if I don't need all the registers the best way is to use PTRACE_PEEKUSER as number of registers I need?

as per code above. `PTRACE_GETREGS` is not iteration over `PTRACE_PEEKUSER`.
so `PTRACE_GETREGS` seems a better option as per @Nate Eldredge 's comment.
multiple syscall has higher cost than getting registers.

> Is the performance depend on architecture (x86/Arm)?

yes, ptrace code is different so it will have impact also number of registers will also change and assembly instructions to read registers will be different.

---

these are the answer best of knowledge. 
if you have some more questions/doubts/clarifications feel free to comment I will try my best to answer them.

### lastly my 2 cents about performance

performance is dependent on various factors so along with optimally coding , practical test comparisons are better way ahead.
use code to create multiple tests and execute them to verify your hypothesis about it.
so many things happen in hardware and compiler optimisations so

#### test your code on arm and x86 to know right answer about performance in your specific case.